# RSpec collection without running tests

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

Is there a way to trigger RSpec test case collection, but not run the tests?

In Python's pytest, the equivalent is appending a `--collect-only` switch.

**My use case**: I would like to run a hook that validates some metadata about our test cases, such as enforcing a mandatory tagging pattern, and I'd like to include this validation check as a PR check. The issue is, I don't really want the test suite to run, but I would only like to validate test case metadata.

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything for this specifically. [Here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/metadata) is the documentation for rspec metadata if that helps at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no built-in way to do collection only. Instead, I had to add the following in my `spec_helper`. Basically, skip the test if you pass in an environment variable `CONTEXT=validate` into your test run. Not really a great way to do this but it seems RSpec provides no built-in alternative:

```rb
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    # validate test case metadata. Ensure proper folder structure and team tagging
    # No need to run tests during validation, so they are skipped and left in 'pending' state
    if CONTEXT == 'validate'
      puts '[INFO] Skipping spec run and validating spec'
      example.skip
      validate_spec(example)
    else
      example.run
    end
```